# Find where $a$ belong to

Tags: trigonometry

Let the equation $x – \sin x = a$ has a unique root in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ then $a\in$

Please provide me any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the **range** of $f(x)=x - \sin x$ in the given interval. The function is strictly increasing as $f'(x) > 0$. So $f(x)$ is injective. Therefore the solution of $g(x) = a$ and $f(x)$ will be unique.

So the interval of $a$ will be range of $x-\sin x$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is Injective over R because its increasing, plug in the values of the domain to find the range i.e $-Pi/2 -Sin(-Pi/2)=-.570796$ and $Pi/2-Sin(Pi/2)=.570796$. Any number in that range will yield a unique solution in our domain. The domain must be reals because if complex numbers are allowed f(i) and f(-i) would be equal.